# Showing the upper and lower menu panes in Virtual box windows guest

Tags: virtualbox

Somehow I've managed to destroy the upper and the lower panes in one of my VirtualBox guests.      Here's how the bad one looks [image: the bad one]

And here's the good one[image]

In the first VM I want to be able to display both the top pane that says File, Machine, View, etc and the bottom pane, that displays various icons and "Right Ctrl"  on the right.    Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User interface settings can be made for any virtual machine from the Virtualbox Manager in the *Settings > User Interface* dialog after selecting a virtual machine:

[image]

Just tick the affected bars if unticked.