# How to Select host USB device for access from the guest?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I want to use USB on my VirtualBox Windows 10(guest).This is my USB
[image]

This is my VBoxManage output

```
 VBoxManage list usbhost
Host USB Devices:

UUID:               95889d61-8b37-4088-ae5b-fc6500bb05fc
VendorId:           0x275d (275D)
ProductId:          0x0ba6 (0BA6)
Revision:           1.0 (0100)
Port:               3
USB version/speed:  1/Low
Product:            USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4//device:/dev/vboxusb/001/002
Current State:      Busy

UUID:               1d8a7ecf-85dd-4320-bd9b-03e7ae8540e3
VendorId:           0x058f (058F)
ProductId:          0x6387 (6387)
Revision:           1.5 (0105)
Port:               0
USB version/speed:  2/High
Manufacturer:       Generic
Product:            Mass Storage
SerialNumber:       35CE8FB1
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1//device:/dev/vboxusb/001/004
Current State:      Busy
```

But the problem is when I enter VirtualBox.Where should I find device to properly set host and guest?

EDIT

I HAVE SOLVED THIS,THIS helps
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB

Comment: Add the usb, see the little icon on the lower right , looks like a usb connection, with a green "+" icon ?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Comment: @Takkat I can not find devices menu,4.

Comment: It is an interface setting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/956397/showing-the-upper-and-lower-menu-panes-in-virtual-box-windows-guest